# What can cause the move command to return "0 files?"

Tags: windows-xp, batch

I have a batch file which uses a move command to pull files from another computer:

```
move \\otherpc\source\directory\*.bin c:\destination\
```

Normally, if there are indeed no files which match the pattern move will print:

> A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.

If the other computer could not be found/reached, it would print:

> The network path was not found.

But I have a move command which returned:

> 0 file(s) moved.

Notes:

- There are files which match the pattern
- The destination folder does exist
- The user has read-write privileges on both directories (source and destination)
- None of the files are read-only.
- The destination drive is not full.

What else am I missing? What could cause a move to behave like this?

Comment: What if you wrap the source in quotation marks? It's possible that there's a `.bin` file that contains a space or a strange character.

Comment: just try listing files in that directory with dir to make sure that command prompt is able to detect files eligible for moving

Comment: @RandolphWest They should not, plain ascii and all legal characters, but I will try.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure what is causing your problems, but I do know about a potential fix: [`robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx)

`move` has been around since DOS times and hasn't changed much since. Along with `xcopy`, it's superseeded by the new and improved `robocopy`. The latter is much more versatile, and a little less buggy in some cases (networking being one of them).

From `robocopy /?`:

```
      Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]

     source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
       file :: File(s) to copy  (names/wildcards: default is "*.*").

        ...

       /MOV :: MOVe files (delete from source after copying).
      /MOVE :: MOVE files AND dirs (delete from source after copying).
```

This commmand is the equivalent to your `move` command:

```
robocopy \\otherpc\source\directory c:\destination *.bin /mov
```

If that works, don't bother why `move` doesn't. If it doesn't, here's a couple of other potential problems and workarounds:

- There's an open file handle on the source files.
- The source files are corrupted.
- The source files have improper names.
- The other PC's OS and/or the file system isn't fully compatible isn't fully compatible with Windows.
- You can always try to `copy` first and `del` on success. I never managed to understand why, but that works sometimes when `move` doesn't...